# wifi network interface name

Tags: android, networking, wifi

I am developing an android app in which phone connects to a wifi network or acts as a wifi access point. I need to get the correct interface name.When phone connects to a wifi network on a mac, interface name is 'eth0' and when it acts as an access point it is 'wl0.1'.

I find this using NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces() which lists all interfaces. I want to get active wifi interface name only.Any help on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NetworkInterface` has `getHardwareAddress` for returning the hardware (MAC) address of the interface. `WifiInfo`, representing the current state of Wi-Fi (obtained by `WifiManager.getConnectionInfo`) has `getMacAddress` method. Just use the latter to find your Wi-Fi interace.

Remember that when comparing the addresses, you should convert them to common format as `getHardwareAddress` returns array of bytes while `getMacAddress` returns string with colon-separated hex values.

Answer (score 2):

As far is I know, there are two ways to obtain the interface name of the Wi-Fi adaptor on an Android device, using Java.  Via either the Wi-Fi interface's:

1. MAC address, through [WifiInfo's getMacAddress()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiInfo.html#getMacAddress())
2. IP address, through [WifiInfo's getIpAddress()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiInfo.html#getIpAddress())

Once you have either piece of information, you can use [NetworkInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/NetworkInterface.html) to figure out the rest.

**Option #1, via MAC address, is likely the best option**.  MAC addresses are are always available, even when a device is not on a network.  It might actually be desirable to some people to get the interface name when the device is not connected to a network.  MAC addresses never change, and if so rarely.  So doing it through the Wi-Fi adaptor's MAC address promises to be more robust.

Here is an example on how to get the Wi-Fi interface name through its MAC address.  It is an expansion on *Xion*'s original answer.

```
protected String wifiInterfaceName(final Context context) {

    // Get WiFi interface's MAC address as a BigInteger.
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
    String wifiMacString = wifiInfo.getMacAddress();
    byte[] wifiMacBytes = macAddressToByteArray(wifiMacString);
    BigInteger wifiMac = new BigInteger(wifiMacBytes);

    String result = null;
    try {
        List<NetworkInterface> networkInterfaces
                = Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces());

        for (NetworkInterface currentInterface : networkInterfaces) {

            byte[] hardwareAddress = currentInterface.getHardwareAddress();
            if (hardwareAddress != null) {
                BigInteger currentMac = new BigInteger(hardwareAddress);

                if (currentMac.equals(wifiMac)) {
                    result = currentInterface.getName();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (SocketException ex) {
        Log.e("WifiGet", "Socket excpetion: " + ex.getMessage());
    }

    return result;
}

protected byte[] macAddressToByteArray(String macString) {
    String[] mac = macString.split("[:\\s-]");
    byte[] macAddress = new byte[6];
    for (int i = 0; i < mac.length; i++) {
        macAddress[i] = Integer.decode("0x" + mac[i]).byteValue();
    }

    return macAddress;
}
```

Option #2, via IP address, is pretty well explained in the question section of: [Get Wifi Interface name on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980826/get-wifi-interface-name-on-android).  There are a few things to be aware of when trying to get the Wi-Fi interface name by IP address:

- It only works when the device is connected to a Wi-Fi network.
- IP addresses change so there is a very small chance your operation will fail if you catch the device changing IP address.
- This one I am still trying to figure out.  But there might be issues with the endianness of various devices and the result from [WifiInfo getIpAddress()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiInfo.html#getIpAddress()).  Again, I'm not sure.  All I know for certain is that I have to reverse byte order in order for me to get the actual IP address.

The following example is based on the question part of [Get Wifi Interface name on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980826/get-wifi-interface-name-on-android)

```
protected String wifiInterfaceName2(final Context context) {

    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
    int ipAddress = wifiInfo.getIpAddress();

    // Convert little-endian to big-endianif needed
    if (ByteOrder.nativeOrder().equals(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)) {
        ipAddress = Integer.reverseBytes(ipAddress);
    }

    byte[] bytes = BigInteger.valueOf(ipAddress).toByteArray();

    String result;
    try {
        InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByAddress(bytes);
        NetworkInterface netInterface = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(addr);
        result = netInterface.getName();
    } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
        LOG.error("Unknown host.", ex);
        result = null;
    } catch (SocketException ex) {
        LOG.error("Socket exception.", ex);
        result = null;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Please keep in mind that both code segments have been provided as examples only.  Make sure to clean up the code, add error handling, and test if you plan on using either in production.

Oh, and don't forget to add the proper permissions to your *AndroidManifest.xml* as well.  I think they are something along the lines of:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Also, these examples will only work on an actual device.  No Wi-Fi on the emulators.

Comment: The endiannes got me crazy, I couldn't find by InetAddress. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Any Android version without root:

```
ls /sys/class/ieee80211/*/device/net/
```

If device name starts with **wl** is wireless. Oherwise is **p2p**.
Example: wlan0, wlp2s0, etc