# How to redirect the user from his input site address to specific ip address?

Tags: java, android, ip

When user is connect to my hotspot i want to redirect him to specific ip.

For example if he wrotes "www.stackoverflow.com" he will redirects to 192.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080.

For each address he will redirects to this ip.

I created android app, maybe there is a way to catch the event when user is connecting to my hotspot when the app is working??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android WIFI How To Detect When Specific WIFI Connection is Available](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9353005/android-wifi-how-to-detect-when-specific-wifi-connection-is-available)

Comment: Its not the same.. i need to redirect from some address to other address