# Wifi event when new wifi available or disappeared

Tags: android, broadcast, wifimanager

I am searching for the event that broadcasts when new wifi is available or already available wifi is disappeared.

I know about SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION of WifiManager but it broadcasts after every scan. I can achieve this by saving scan result in preference and comparing it next time but I think this will become resource consuming.

Thanks in advance for any solution.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html try this

Comment: Check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9353005/android-wifi-how-to-detect-when-specific-wifi-connection-is-available