# Detecting specific wifi connections on a native mobile app

Tags: javascript, react-native, wifi

I am looking at ways to detect when a specific connection is available. For example when the user gets home and the network is picked up they are able to be given a notification as to whether they would like to join the network. At the minute I am trying to do this in React so would be interested in what options I have available native or not.

I have seen this previous question which is along very similar lines but I am not currently looking specifically for android.
[Android WIFI How To Detect When Specific WIFI Connection is Available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9353005/android-wifi-how-to-detect-when-specific-wifi-connection-is-available)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `NetInfo` for this. You can find specific documentation [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/netinfo.html).

Here is a quick example of what you are trying to do:

```
NetInfo.addEventListener(
   'change',
   function(reach) {
       if(reach.toLowerCase() === 'wifi' ) {
           console.log('You are on wifi!');
       }
   }
);
```