# How to log the data using WIFI connection in android log entries SDK

Tags: android, logentries, android-log

I want to know is there any way to determine whatever I am logging should go through WIFI instead of device network,Is there any methods as part of Log entries SDK

Comment: go through this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9353005/android-wifi-how-to-detect-when-specific-wifi-connection-is-available

Comment: Is there any default option in sdk

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for wifi connection or not.

```
 private boolean checkConnectedToDesiredWifi() {
    boolean connected = false;
    WifiManager wifiManager =(WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiInfo wifiInf = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
    String desiredMacAddress = wifiInf.getMacAddress();
    WifiInfo wifi = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
    if (wifi != null) {
        // get current router Mac address
        String bssid = wifi.getBSSID();
        connected = desiredMacAddress.equals(bssid);
    }

    return connected;
}
```

Comment: I am asking is there any default option in this SDK,to be used,I dont what to check for WIFI connection and log it manually from my end