# Energy efficient detection of location change in Mobile computing

Tags: android, mobile, location, energy

I am currently developing a service which runs in a background on Android OS. As soon as I change my location service runs some tasks. For instance: as I enter the office, restaurant or home service should start working.  I want it to be energy efficient, so using the GPS service or Accelerometer all the time is very bad idea. I was thinking of constantly checking for wi-fi connections and if current networks vary from the ones that were available some time before I run my tasks. I wonder how efficient is this idea in terms of energy efficiency and context awareness and if there are any better ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems "checking for wi-fi connections" is better approach. But actually not "checking", but use `BroadcastReceiver` to find out that WiFi network has changed like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13343417/6950238) [petersyn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1245231/petrsyn)'s answer. Anyway, You can implement all approaches and compare results.